# Postgresql current datetime for past year

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a function on postgresql that will let me get the current datetime for the past year or x number of past years?
I know i can do this `select  now() - interval '1 year';` but in a function how can i put the number of years in a variable

```
x := '2 year'
Is it possible to do this select  now() - interval x;
```

I tried but it give me error

Comment: Which version of postgresql are you using ?

Comment: the version is 9.5

Comment: `select now() - make_interval(years := 1);`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use variable you can do this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func(input integer)
  RETURNS TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE  AS
  $BODY$ 
  declare 
        result TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE; 
  begin
        select  now() - (input  || ' years')::interval into result;
        return result;
  end;
  $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

Answer (score 2):

For the date, you would use:

```
select current_date - interval '1 year'
```

For the date/time:

```
select now() - interval '1 year'
```